# Exclude linq join condition based on parameter

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to be able to dynamically exclude join based on boolean parameters, look at the code below, how can I exclude the join if the 'includeJoin' variable is false or is there another way to dynamically add joins

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
        fooList.Add(new Foo{Foo_Id = 1});
        fooList.Add(new Foo{Foo_Id = 2});

        List<Bar> barList = new List<Bar>();
        barList.Add(new Bar{Foo_Id = 1});
        barList.Add(new Bar{Foo_Id = 1});

        IQueryable<Foo> fooQuery = fooList.AsQueryable();
        IQueryable<Bar> barQuery = barList.AsQueryable();

        bool includeJoin = false;

        var foos = from f in fooList

                   //Exclude this join if includeJoin vairable is false!!
                   join b in barList on f.Foo_Id equals b.Foo_Id into g
                   from result in g.DefaultIfEmpty()


                   select new Foo { Foo_Id = f.Foo_Id };

        var results = foos.ToList();
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public int Foo_Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public int Foo_Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is possible by simply building two different LINQ queries:

```
bool includeJoin = false;

IEnumerable<Foo> foos;

if (includeJoin)
{
    foos = from f in fooList

                //Exclude this join if includeJoin vairable is false!!
                join b in barList on f.Foo_Id equals b.Foo_Id into g
                from result in g.DefaultIfEmpty()


                select new Foo { Foo_Id = f.Foo_Id };
}
else
{
    foos = from f in fooList select new Foo { Foo_Id = f.Foo_Id };
}

var results = foos.ToList();
```

With this solution, you can simply build two independent LINQ queries which will result in an IEnumerable in either way. As they both result in the same type (IEnumerable), you can then simply use foos.ToList() at the end to get the list with the values.